# New Page problem

Tags: page-breaking, templates, page

I'm new with latex and I've been having some issues when using an template not created for me. 
My issue is that in the document, everytime I declare a chapter and finish a section, it creates a new page after that, but I don't want it. I want that all the content without new pages separating the sections.

Here's the configuration code:

```
\documentclass[
    % -- opções da classe memoir --
    12pt,               % tamanho da fonte
    openright,          % capítulos começam em pág ímpar (insere página vazia caso preciso)
    twoside,            % para impressão em recto e verso. Oposto a oneside
    a4paper,            % tamanho do papel. 
    english,            % idioma adicional para hifenização
    brazil              % o último idioma é o principal do documento
    ]{abntex2}

% Pacotes básicos 
\usepackage{lmodern}            % Usa a fonte Latin Modern          
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Selecao de codigos de fonte.
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Codificacao do documento (conversão automática dos acentos)
\usepackage{indentfirst}        % Indenta o primeiro parágrafo de cada seção.
\usepackage{color}              % Controle das cores
\usepackage{graphicx}           % Inclusão de gráficos
\usepackage{microtype}          % para melhorias de justificação

% Pacotes adicionais, usados apenas no âmbito do Modelo Canônico do abnteX2
\usepackage{lipsum}             % para geração de dummy text

% Pacotes de citações
\usepackage[brazilian,hyperpageref]{backref}     % Paginas com as citações na bibl
\usepackage[alf]{abntex2cite}   % Citações padrão ABNT
```

In my document is like:

**Abstract**

content

*New blank page*

**Other chapter or whatever**

content

*New blank page*

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! You must add the `body` of document to the MWE, otherwise it is impossible to know what happens.

Comment: you declare (with option `open right`), that chapters should start on right (odd) page. so if previous chapter finish on odd page, you have one blank page before new chapter. replace this option with `openany`.

Comment: *`% capítulos começam em pág ímpar (insere página vazia caso preciso)`* What does that mean in english?

Comment: google translation: chapters start at odd page (inserts empty page if necessary). op is informed about this ...

Comment: what you mean with `section`?. sections follows each other with any page break. empty page is inserted (when needed ) only at beginning of chapters, if you declare option `openright`.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear. I suspect, that you talking about chapters (not sections), for which you like that start on any new page immediately after end of the previous page.

To confirm this, please compare the next two document example:

- your code

  ```
  \documentclass[12pt,
      openright,    % <-----
      a4paper, twoside, english, brazil]{abntex2}

  \usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
  \begin{document}
  \chapter{first chapter}
  \lipsum[1]
  \section{first section}
  \lipsum[2]
  \chapter{second chapter}
  \lipsum
  \end{document}
  ```
- desired result?

  ```
  \documentclass[12pt,
      openany,    % <-----
      a4paper, twoside, english, brazil]{abntex2}

  \usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text
  \begin{document}
  \chapter{first chapter}
  \lipsum[1]
  \section{first section}
  \lipsum[2]
  \chapter{second chapter}
  \lipsum
  \end{document}
  ```

let us know, is the second example is what you looking for.

Comment: It didn't change anything, but it gave me the way to see that it was this line that I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I got what I wanted changing the \documentclass

```
twoside
```

for

```
oneside
```

It looks like it is the way the page was printed. 
Anyways, thanks for all that took a minute to help me :)